# How to style contribution and event registration pages?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

I want to style totally different a contribution page, not even having the general website header, no left menu with the login, nothing.
Just to use its functionality, but create new html for an event registration form, or for a contribution page.

Comment: It may help if you mention your CMS

Comment: Sorry, I am using CiviCRM 4.7.22 on Drupal

Comment: To state @Davejenx's answer a little differently - theming is handled by Drupal.  So you can get better answers on the Drupal Stack Exchange.  Davejenx's answer is good if you know how to create Drupal themes and are willing to start from scratch.  However, if you don't know Drupal themes, you can still [hide blocks](https://www.drupal.org/node/988544) and other Drupal tricks.

Answer (score 2):

One approach in Drupal would be the [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) + [ThemeKey CiviCRM](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey_civicrm) modules. There's a [Drupal 7 version of ThemeKey CiviCRM](https://github.com/fuzionnz/themekey_civicrm). This allows you to use a different theme for specified Civi pages. So you could create a minimal theme and use that for the desired pages.